# How to close a stream opened by FFmpeg?

Tags: objective-c, ffmpeg

I'm currently playing around with FFmpeg, and based myself on [this github project](https://github.com/durfu/DFURTSPPlayer/blob/master/DFURTSPPlayer/DFURTSPPlayer/FFMpegDecoder/RTSPPlayer.m).

I'd like the ability to close the stream when I want it to close.

How could I achieve this?
If I just extract the part in the `dealloc` method and call that when needed it crashes.

I've read about an interrupt callback that needs to be called, but I have no idea how to do so. (C-code isn't in my current skillset, so understanding it is a bit hard).

Callback I referred to, but have no idea how to use :

```
pFormatCtx->interrupt_callback.opaque;
pFormatCtx->interrupt_callback.callback;
```

Is there a certain order I need to respect, things I need to do upfront or in the other methods ?

Thanks!

Current :

```
-(void) stopCapturing {
    if (pFrame) av_free(&pFrame);
    if (pCodecCtx) avcodec_close(pCodecCtx);

    if (img_convert_ctx) sws_freeContext(img_convert_ctx);
    avpicture_free(&picture);
    if (pFormatCtx) avformat_close_input(&pFormatCtx);
}
```

Comment: 2 things - first of all, when you get a crash, please post a backtrace + code. Second, I don't see why dealloc wouldn't work for you. The video file object doesn't need to exist for the lifetime of your app, just create a new object each time you want to re-start recording, and release the reference to the object when you're done with it.

Comment: It's not about the crash per-se. I'm asking what the proper way is to release everything, as I want to be able to do so on demand.

Comment: Oh, I see, the code you're quoting is the proper way to release the ffmpeg variables. I think the crash may be unrelated to the closing itself, and rather be related to reuse of an already-closed variable elsewhere in your code. (Note that you didn't assign NULL to pcodecctx/img_convert_ctx after closing them.)

Comment: @RonaldS.Bultje Thanks, I'll try. So the callback is not really necessary ?

Comment: Oh sorry, forgot. It's unrelated: the callback is for network connections waiting for data. The callback is called intermittently to ask if we should abort waiting for more data. If so, the reading will terminate with a timeout error. Else, the waiting for data will continue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For further reference**

RonaldS.Bultje was so kind as to provide the following answer:

> I think the crash may be unrelated to the closing itself, and rather be related to reuse of an already-closed variable elsewhere in your code. (Note that you didn't assign NULL to pcodecctx/img_convert_ctx after closing them.) – Ronald S. Bultje Sep 10 '15 at 15:52
>
> The callback is unrelated, it is for network connections waiting for data. The callback is called intermittently to ask if we should abort waiting for more data. If so, the reading will terminate with a timeout error. Else, the waiting for data will continue. - Ronald S. Bultje Sep 14 '15 at 10:41